# Itext generated pdf throws error at opening

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, itext

I am using itext pdf version 5.3.4. Until recent the code worked ok but the client needed some modifications and now when opening the generated pdf the following error is shown " "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. please contact the person who created the pdf document to correct the problem".

I will put below the piece of code where i think the error is and also explain it a little bit. Basically i have a collection of rows that i am iterating and i want the content to be shown toghether (that's why i am using generalTable variable). Below is the code and if i can give you anymore details please let me know :

```
            PdfPTable generalTable = new PdfPTable(2);
            generalTable.setKeepTogether(true);
            generalTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
            Iterator rows = objects.iterator();
            String ratingCellText = "";
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                SupplierSearchRecord rec = (SupplierSearchRecord)rows.next();
                if (rec.getMgID() == mgVO.getId() &&
                        rec.getGaID() == gzVO.getId()) {
                    String cellText = "";
                    if (company != rec.getCompanyId()) {
                        if (ratingCellText.length() > 0) {
                            PdfPCell myCell1 = PdfUtil.makeCell(simpleFont, PdfUtil.getText(ratingCellText));
                            myCell1.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
                            myCell1.setColspan(2);
                            generalTable.addCell(myCell1);
                            ratingCellText = "";
                        }
                        generalTable.addCell(PdfUtil.makeCell(simpleFont, PdfUtil.getText("\n\n" + rec.getCompanyTitle())));
                        String duns = "\n\n" + ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyDuns()))?txtUtil.msg("optioncompanyDuns")+": ":"") +
                                   PdfUtil.getText(rec.getCompanyDuns()) ;
                        generalTable.addCell(PdfUtil.makeCell(simpleFont, duns));

                        String tel = ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyPhone1()))?"    Tel: ":"") +
                                   PdfUtil.getText(rec.getCompanyPhone1()) +
                                  ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyPhone1()))?", ":"") ;
                        String fax = ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyFax()))?"Fax: ":"") +
                                   PdfUtil.getText(rec.getCompanyFax()) +
                                  ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyFax()))?", ":"") ;
                        String homePage = ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyInternetAddress()))?txtUtil.msg("optioncompanyInternetAddress")+": ":"") +
                                           PdfUtil.getText(rec.getCompanyInternetAddress()) +
                                          ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyInternetAddress()))?", ":"") ;
                        String email = ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyEmail()))?"Email: ":"") +
                                   PdfUtil.getText(rec.getCompanyEmail()) +
                                  ((isNotEmpty(rec.getCompanyEmail()))?", ":"") ;

                        cellText = "\n" + PdfUtil.getText(rec.getCompanyAddress()) + ", " + PdfUtil.getText(rec.getCompanyPostalCode()+ ", " + rec.getCompanyCity() + ", " + rec.getCompanyCountryTitle()) + "\n" +
                                            tel +
                                            fax +
                                            homePage +
                                            email;
                        PdfPCell myCell = PdfUtil.makeCell(simpleFont, PdfUtil.getText(cellText));
                        myCell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                        myCell.setColspan(2);
                        generalTable.addCell(myCell);
                    }
                    company = rec.getCompanyId();
                    document.add(generalTable);
                    generalTable.deleteBodyRows();
```

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: "please contact the person who created the pdf document to correct the problem" every developer wants to read this...

Comment: Please also share a sample PDF illustrating the issue. That been said, have you tested your code with a more current iText version?

Comment: @mkl it is a standard Adobe Reader error. I have not tested the code with a more current version, i will give it a try thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you shared a sample PDF produced by your code, people could analyze it and look for the reason why Adobe Reader is unhappy.

Comment: @mkl i cannot do that because a sample pdf contains data from our clients so it's a delicate matter to provide such a sample. Maybe the code can help you help me if not i will have to find another way.

Comment: Please try and reproduce the issue using non-sensitive data. If you succeed, we'll have something to work with. If you don't succeed, there is something very special about your data.